# Borderlands 2 executable details version isn't correct

Tags: borderlands-2, version-differences

I play Borderlands 2 with some coworkers some of whom have the Mac version of Borderlands 2 and other have the PC version (myself included). Because the Mac version is distributed by a different developer we can't play together unless our versions match up which occasionally isn't the case due to Steam's auto-update.  So I've turned off auto update.

I'm trying to verify the version I have installed by finding the executable in explorer and going into properties and the details tab but it says I have 1.0.77 which know is incorrect.  Has anyone else encountered this and did you find a way to get the correct version?

Answer (score 1):

From the main menu, go to **Matchmaking**->**Match Browser**. There, in the bottom right corner of the dialog, will be your game version, like **1.4.0**.