# How do I check which version of the game it is that I have?

Tags: borderlands-2

At first, I read to check the Details of the Properties of the Borderlands2.exe, but then I read that those [Details are incorrect](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/113515/borderlands-2-executable-details-version-isnt-correct) and [the proper way to check is in the bottom right of the Match browser menu](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/113524/46216). So, I guess my question is, what is the standard? This is for the purpose of the [documentation of glitch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/177449/how-do-i-do-the-infinite-ammo-glitch)es.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "official" standard.

But if you ask speedrunners on which version they run, they say versions like 1.3 or 1.8.1, which are the ones in your matchmaking browser.
Additionally if you patch the version of your game up or down with any patcher available, you will be able to choose between the versionnumbers, that you find in your matchmaking browser.

So if you want to document all of the glitches, I would recommend using the version from your matchmaking browser.